# Shortest path (point to point) when filling out coordinates in boxes

Tags: qgis-3, coordinates, shortest-path

I am using the processing toolbox interface to launch the `"Shortest path (point to point)"` command to connect two points using a line network layer (see attached photo).

[image]

If I fill out the starting and ending point coordinates of the Parameters Window by clicking directly in the screen, the algoritm works fine, but if I write out directly the coordinates of the two points in the Start Point and End Point boxes

[image]

I always get

> There is no route from start point to end point.

[image]

Why I am getting this error if there is a route to connect both points?

I am using Windows 10, I have 16 GB of memory, Intel Core i7 vPro. QGIS version 3.12.0-Bucuresti

Comment: All elements, point coordinates and line network layer use the same CRS, EPSG:25832. The point coordinates that I type in box are the one used to upload the point layer, so coordinates should be fine

Comment: By doing the  "Split with lines" command to the input line network layer, the algorithm has worked fine. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

> Credits to @MrXsquared from his answer
> https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/308137/99589

Before processing it is necessary to connect lines via nodes. For that use ["Split with lines"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#split-with-lines) geoalgorithm. By choosing line layer as *'Input layer'* as well as *'Split layer'* it will brake lines into linestrings on vertices where lines intersect.

And afterwards continue with ["Shortest path (point to point)"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html#shortest-path-point-to-point).

P.S. Mind that both layers (points and lines) have to share the same CRS. Moreover, it may be useful to check the consistency and topological correctness of lines beforehand.